# How to send Data from one fragment to other, both hosted by different activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have Fragment A hosted by Activity A and Fragment B hosted by Activity B. Fragment A calls Activity B. I want to send data back to Fragment B to Fragment A. I tried overriding `setResult` but it didn't work.

Comment: You can do it easily with EventBus.

Answer (score 1):

From your  `FragmentA` call the `ActivityB` using  startActivityForResult() method

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 12345);
```

In your ActivityB set the data which you want to return back to ActivityA. If you don't want to return back, don't set any.

For example: In ActivityB if you want to send back data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

If you don't want to return data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your FragmentA class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 12345) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Write your code if there's no result
        }
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

Comment: I am making a note taking app, the second fragment tells the first one whether the note was successful or not. I am not able to send the result via setResult

Answer (score 0):

Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html then anything that needs to know what happened can register a receiver for it.